# Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 16:13. No Property of name Cliked found

Tags: c#, xaml, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I'm following a tutorial to make an app that receives and sends data to a web service.
But the time to create a button on the MainPage to bring the registration screen of the Visual Studio this error

```
 Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException:. Position 16:13 In the Property of name Cliked found
```

and I lost because my this code like the tutorial.

Comment: You need to post you XAML.

Comment: I suppose inside your Xaml class you have a view/object that is not named or named incorrectly and you are trying to access it from other site.

Answer (score 1):

**Xaml:**

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Button Clicked="Btn_Clicked" Text = "test button" />

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ContactList}"
            HasUnevenRows="True">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="12,6">
              <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="24"/>
              <Label Text="{Binding Email}" FontSize="24"/>
              <Label Text="{Binding City}" FontSize="24"/>
              <Label Text="{Binding State}" FontSize="24"/>
              <Label Text="{Binding Zip}" FontSize="24"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
```

**Xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ContactManagerApp.Views
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private async void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new NewContactPage()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Clicked` is an event not a property so you cannot bind it. You should Bind `Command` property of `Button`. You should add a method into page.xaml.cs if you want to use `Clicked` event.

**Xaml:**

```
< Button Clicked="Btn_Clicked" Text = "test button" />
```

**Xaml.cs**

```
private void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Hi so I tried to do this and is still having the same error.